# Indermediate sub-patch Node.js package version

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning

I'm providing accompanying package that matches the version of the main NPM package, already in `major.minor.patch` format (e.g. `1.3.1`).

I don't want to break version conformity between main and accompanying package. Is it possible to release intermediary subpatches for accompanying package that match

```
>=1.3.1 <1.3.2
```

semver constraint? Similar to `1.3.1.1`.

Even if not possible to match the constraint, what's the convention for the patch for `1.3.1` to make it not overlap `1.3.2`?

Answer (score 4):

As http://semver.org/ states

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> - MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
> - MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
> - PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.
> - Additional labels for pre-release and build metadata are available as extensions to the MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH format.

As there is no `sub-patches` in SemVer, you could label your version with a label, for example `1.3.2-alpha1` or similar.

`npm` doesn't install labelled versions, commonly release candidates labeled with `rc`, alphas, betas and so on without explicitly stating you want to install such version.

Comment: I see. So I guess it can be either `1.3.2-patch.0-1.3.1` or `1.3.2-rc.0`, since none of them will match loose version constraints.

Comment: @estus, exactly. But beware, versions like `1.3.2-patch.0-1.3.1` were sort of the reason `SemVer` was proposed: to have semantic meaning behind the version numbers alone.